# Write error with spark.write against SQL Server table (via JDBC Connection)

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, sql-server-2005

We are trying to save a DataFrame in SQL Server (V2005) using the following method:

```
df_cards.write.jdbc(url=conn_str, table=tablename, mode='append', properties=properties)
```

However, we encountered the following error:

> org.apache.spark.SparkSQLException: Unrecognized SQL type -151

The most puzzling part is that the data has been saved in the database.

Somebody can help us?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You are using a version of SQL Server that is  so long out of support it's no surprise it behaves unexpectedly

Comment: It sometimes chokes like this in [getCatalystType()](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L178) when selecting back the data back from the target table. Do you have a column with a user-defined type in the target table?

Comment: Hi AlwaysLearning.

We have the problem with two columns of type datetime in SQL, dont have  a user-defined type in the target table . We suspect that because when we do a select we must cast those columns.

Any idea to solve it?